# Como hacer que esta barra de busqueda funcione pero con variables en lugar de string's?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy tratando de hacer una barra de búsqueda con los valores que he guardado en variables, la variable que quiero usar es title0 y se crean en una clase llamada 'MostPopular'. este es el código:

```
Future<MostPopular> obtenerInfo() async {
 final respuesta = await Dio().get(
     'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=0e685fd77fb3d76874a3ac26e0db8a4b&language=en-US&page=1');

 final Map<String, dynamic> json = respuesta.data;

 final MostPopular mostpopular = MostPopular.fromJson(json);

 return mostpopular;
}


class MostPopular {
 MostPopular({
   this.title0,

 }
);

final String title0;
```

Esta factory está conectada a una api y aquí simplemente asigno los valores del json a las variables

```
factory MostPopular.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final String title0 =
        (json["results"] as List).map((j) => j["title"]).toList()[0];


return MostPopular(
      title0: title,
     
  )}
```

```
class Buscador extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Search Bar',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
String filter = '';
List<String> list = [
 'a', 'b', 'c',
];

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 controller.addListener(() {
   setState(() {
     filter = controller.text;
   });
 });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
   body: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Row(
         children: <Widget>[
           Expanded(
             child: Container(
               height: 80,
               width: double.infinity,
               padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                 top: 35,
                 left: 15,
                 right: 5,
                 bottom: 5,
               ),
               child: TextField(
                 controller: controller,
                 autofocus: false,
                 decoration: InputDecoration(
                   labelText: 'Search Something',
                   filled: true,
                   fillColor: Colors.white,
                   enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
                     borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                   ),
                   focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
                     borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ),
           Container(
             height: 80,
             padding: EdgeInsets.only(
               top: 25,
               right: 15,
             ),
             child: Icon(Icons.search),
           )
         ],
       ),
       Expanded(
         child: ListView.builder(
           itemCount: list.length,
           itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
             return list[index].toLowerCase().contains(filter.toLowerCase())
                 ? Padding(
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                       horizontal: 22.0,
                       vertical: 10.0,
                     ),
                     child: Text(
                       list[index],
                       style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                     ),
                   )
                 : SizedBox.shrink();
           },
         ),
       )
     ],
   ),
 );
}
```

Quiero cambiar 'a', 'b', 'c' por la variable llamada title0 para que me muestre el valor de title0.
Aquí hay una mejor explicación: el código que muestro en la publicación, es una barra de búsqueda que tiene una lista con tres valores, uno es 'a', el segundo es 'b' y el tercero es 'c'. Lo que quiero hacer es cambiar esos tres valores por una variable llamada title0. Intenté cambiarlos así: List  list = [title0]; pero no funcionó, ¿cómo solucionarlo para que pueda mostrarme el valor de la variable llamada title0? Gracias!